# Getting E1101 errors ("no member") from spyder's static code analysis

Tags: spyder, pylint, pylintrc

Lately (since something changed in spyder or pylint or ?), I have been getting E1101 errors ("no member") from spyder's static code analysis on astropy.constants symbols. No idea why or what changed.

Answer (score 1):

My simplistic solution for all users on a Linux or Unix system (Mac is probably similar) was to create an /etc/pylintrc as follows:

```
[TYPECHECK]
ignored-modules=astropy.constants
```

Of course, this could, instead, be put in a personal $HOME/.pylintrc file.

And, I could have updated an existing file.